# C# error says " member names can not be the same as their enclosing type"

Tags: c#

I get an error stating that  "'damageScript': member names can not be the same as their enclosing type" It only shows where it says "public HealthDamageInfo damageScript;"

```
internal class damageScript
{

    public HealthDamageInfo damageScript;




    public string tagName;
    public string otherTag;

    public string message;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        damageScript = GetComponent<HealthDamageInfo>();
    }

    private HealthDamageInfo GetComponent<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == tagName)
        {
            damageScript.SendMessage("SwitchInteractionTarget", message);
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.tag == otherTag)
        {
            damageScript.SendMessage("SwitchInteractionTarget", message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class name "damageScript" and the field "damageScript" (the line you referenced) have the same name. Change one of them to something else.

Comment: It's worth noting that your class name is not following proper C# convention of PascalCasing for class names.  You should rename your class to internal class DamageScript

Answer (score 2):

It is as the error says, your class `damageScript` cannot also contain a variable `damageScript`.  If you rename the variable or the class the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

`public HealthDamageInfo damageScript;` is enclosed within `internal class damageScript`.

You have to change either the class name or the member variable's.